# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'. Even with __init__.py

Tags: python, django, module, model

This is my project structure.

```
├─demo_data
├─findb
│  └─__pycache__
├─management
└─tw_equity
    ├─migrations
    │  └─__pycache__       
    └─__pycache__
```

---

Now I try to insert demo data to my models.
So I create `commands.py`for the process.

```py
# ./management/commands.py

from datetime import datetime
from tw_equity.models import (
    TradingDate,
    Basic,
    Price,
    Holder,
)

with open('demo_data/trading_date.csv') as f:

    for row in f:
        data = datetime.strptime(row, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        trading_date = TradingDate(
            trading_date=data
        )
        trading_date.save()

    print('Insert Successfully.')
```

---

**But the error keeps showing up.**

```
(Findb) C:\Users\ycyta\python-django-Findb>management\commands.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ycyta\python-django-Findb\management\commands.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tw_equity.models import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tw_equity'
```

---

**Already tried**

1. `python manage.py shell`, it is all good.

```
(Findb) C:\Users\ycyta\python-django-Findb>python manage.py shell
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from tw_equity.models import TradingDate
>>> TradingDate
<class 'tw_equity.models.TradingDate'>
```

2. Mostly similar questions before were concerned about `__ini__.py`, but I already have.

---

[image: Project folder detail]

---

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You should create a custom management command and call it via `manage.py <custom_command>` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Thxs, I will try it, but still wonder why the `import tw_equity.models` in `commands.py` fail.

Comment: Most likely you have not configured PYTHONPATH correctly

Comment: But why it can be called in command line, not import in `.py` file.

Comment: `manage.py` is called from the project root and the directory of the python script executed is added to the path. When you call a script in a sub-directory the project root is not added to the path, the sub-directory is

Comment: Trying to figure out path problems.  But just solved the problem through building custom command as your suggestion, thxs man.